# Make UITableViewCell's delegate different from the ViewController's datasource

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I currently have a UIViewController with a table view that looks kind of like this:

```
class FeedViewController: UIViewController {
    private var feedViewModel = FeedViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground

        feedViewModel.delegate = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = feedViewModel

        feedViewModel.fetchData()
    }
}

extension FeedViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}

extension FeedViewController: FeedViewModelDelegate {
    func FeedViewModelDidFetchData() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The FeedViewModel class looks something like this:

```
protocol FeedViewModelDelegate: AnyObject {
    func FeedViewModelDidFetchData()
}

public class FeedViewModel: NSObject {
    var feed: Feed?
    
    weak var delegate: FeedViewModelDelegate?
    
    public func fetchData() {
        NetworkingManager.shared.getRequest(endpoint: endpoint, headers: headers) { [weak self] response, error in
            
            self?.feed = feed
            self?.delegate?.FeedViewModelDidFetchData()
        }
    }
}

extension FeedViewModel: UITableViewDataSource {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let feed = feed else { return 0 }
        switch feed.goerPosts[section] {
        case "goer.post":
            return 2
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PostHeaderTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! PostHeaderTableViewCell
                cell.configure(with: postViewModel.header.goer, event: postViewModel.header.event)
                cell.delegate = delegate <------------- ISSUE HERE
                return cell
    }
    
    public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        guard let feed = feed else { return 0 }
        return feed.goerPosts.count
    }
}
```

Here is a cell that I have made for the tableView that has a protocol for which a delegate needs to conform:

```
protocol PostHeaderTableViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func postHeaderTableViewCellDidTapMore()
    func postHeaderTableViewCellDidTapUsername(goer: Goer?)
    func postHeaderTableViewCellDidTapEventName(event: Event?)
    func postHeaderTableViewCellDidTapProfilePicture(goer: Goer?)
}

class PostHeaderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    weak var delegate: PostHeaderTableViewCellDelegate?

    static let identifier = "FeedPostHeaderTableViewCell"

    ... MORE STUFF ...
}
```

The issue arises due to the fact that the cells I have made need a delegate to conform to its protocol. Since the FeedViewModel is the the tableView's datasource. It is in the cellForRowAt function that I create and configure each cell, and presumably where I could set the cell's delegate, but I want the ViewController that owns the FeedViewModel to be the cells delegate, not the viewModel its self.

I am unsure how I can set the FeedViewModel's owning ViewController to be the cell's delegate within the FeedViewModel.

Comment: I think it was a mistake to have `FeedViewModel` implement the data sources methods.  I understand why you want to do it, but it just isn't really how UIKit and UITableview are architected.  There are a few potential solutions; You can add a `cellDelegate: PostHeaderTableViewCellDelegate` property to your view model and then set that property as the cell's delegate or you can add the methods from `PostHeaderTableViewCellDelegate` to `FeedViewModelDelegate` and have your view model simply call the appropriate `FeedViewModelDelegate` method in its `PostHeaderTableViewCellDelegate` functions

Comment: Both of these kind of couple the cell and the view controller to the view model.  I think it is better to face the fact that the `UITableviewDatasource` protocol needs to be part of the view controller and move those functions where they belong

Comment: This feels.... wrong. Think hierarchies, both view controller and view, and think MVC style. This is what a `UITableView` and it's `UIViewController` owner do. A `UITableViewCell` is pretty much "owned" by it's table view - but please, do not forget that each cell is **reuaable**. Cells really should simply "talk" to the table view regardless of anything else via `indexPath`, both for populating and user interaction. If something needs to know what was tapped (and that's what it looks like to me), go through the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks guys. I suppose that since the UITableViewDataSource and the UITableViewDelegate had the opportunity to be separate entities, this was a design paradigm that was used. Cheers.